# How to implement search option with webservice url in ios, using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I'm getting data from a web service.If we pass any string through service url, then it will returns data according to it.I have implemented and display data in a tableview . now what I want is to implement search option for it. so I used uisearchcontroller and to do that.but it is not working well.I mean if we send letter 'y' for the web service, it will return all the results that starts from y. this is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[NSLocalizedString(@"ScopeButtonCountry", @"Airport"), NSLocalizedString(@"ScopeButtonCapital", @"AirportCode")];
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    //self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
    self.mtableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)getAirports:(NSString *)needeedString
{
    airportList = nil;
    needeedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
    NSString *apiKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some api"];
    NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl%@%@",apiKey,needeedString];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:fullUrl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSArray *result = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        airportList = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *all in result)
        {
            Details *d1 = [Details new];
            d1.airport = [all objectForKey:@"Airport"];
            [airportList addObject:d1];
            [self.mtableView reloadData];

        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    if (searchString == nil || [searchString  isEqual: @""]) {
        [self getAirports:@""];
        [self.mtableView reloadData];
    }
    [self getAirports:searchString];
    [self.mtableView reloadData];
}




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [airportList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ci"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ci"];
    }

    Details *newDetails = [airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = newDetails.airport;

    return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Details *newDetails = [airportList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *selectedText = newDetails.airport;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedText forKey:@"st"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: found the answer,I remove `neededString = @" "`. now there is a small problem.I cannot select directly tableview cell, in sorted list.I have to tap once. then it goes to tableviwe with search results.then I hve to relod. why is that.

Answer (score 2):

Call reload in dispatch main queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [self.mtableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below changes I have made ,hope it will work

```
- (void)getAirports:(NSString *)needeedString
    {
        airportList = nil;
        needeedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
        NSString *apiKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some api"];
        NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl%@%@",apiKey,needeedString];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:fullUrl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
        NSArray *result = (NSArray *)responseObject;
        airportList = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSDictionary *all in result)
        {
            Details *d1 = [Details new];
            d1.airport = [all objectForKey:@"Airport"];
            [airportList addObject:d1];
           //remove reload data method from here because it will reload your table on each iteration

        }
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //reload on main thread
       [self.mtableView reloadData];
    });

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    }];
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
    if (searchString != nil && ![searchString  isEqual: @""]) {
       [self getAirports:searchString];
    }
    //here there is no need to reload
   //also changed condition
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess In method

```
- (void)getAirports:(NSString *)needeedString
```

remove

```
[self.mtableView reloadData];
```

outside the for loop

and you can call reloadData like

```
    self.mtableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES
```